# Efficient Find Next Greater in Another Array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Is it possible to remove the for loops in this function and get a speed up in the process?  I have not been able to get the same results with vector methods for this function.  Or is there another option?

```
import numpy as np

indices = np.array(
    [814, 935, 1057, 3069, 3305, 3800, 4093, 4162, 4449])

within = np.array(
    [193, 207, 243, 251, 273, 286, 405, 427, 696,
     770, 883, 896, 1004, 2014, 2032, 2033, 2046, 2066,
     2079, 2154, 2155, 2156, 2157, 2158, 2159, 2163, 2165,
     2166, 2167, 2183, 2184, 2208, 2210, 2212, 2213, 2221,
     2222, 2223, 2225, 2226, 2227, 2281, 2282, 2338, 2401,
     2611, 2612, 2639, 2640, 2649, 2700, 2775, 2776, 2785,
     3030, 3171, 3191, 3406, 3427, 3527, 3984, 3996, 3997,
     4024, 4323, 4331, 4332])


def get_first_ind_after(indices, within):
    """returns array of the first index after each listed in indices

    indices and within must be sorted ascending
    """
    first_after_leading = []
    for index in indices:

        for w_ind in within:

            if w_ind > index:
                first_after_leading.append(w_ind)

                break

    # convert to np array
    first_after_leading = np.array(first_after_leading).flatten()

    return np.unique(first_after_leading)
```

It should return the next greatest number for each in the indices array if there is one.

```
# Output:
[ 883 1004 2014 3171 3406 3984 4323]
```

Comment: Is `within` always sorted?

Comment: yes it will always be sorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one based on `np.searchsorted` -

```
def next_greater(indices, within):
    idx = np.searchsorted(within, indices)
    idxv = idx[idx<len(within)]
    idxv_unq = np.unique(idxv)
    return within[idxv_unq]
```

Alternatively, `idxv_unq` could be computed like so and should be more efficient -

```
idxv_unq = idxv[np.r_[True,idxv[:-1] != idxv[1:]]]
```

Comment: It appears the first one is more efficient on my computer.
12.8 µs ± 691 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
versus
18.6 µs ± 596 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

Comment: @ak_slick Test out on bigger arrays, I would say.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[within[within>x][0] if len(within[within>x])>0 else 0 for x in indices]
```

As in,

```
In [35]: import numpy as np
    ...: indices = np.array([814, 935, 1057, 3069, 3305, 3800, 4093, 4162, 4449])
    ...:
    ...: within = np.array(
    ...:     [193, 207, 243, 251, 273, 286, 405, 427, 696,
    ...:      770, 883, 896, 1004, 2014, 2032, 2033, 2046, 2066,
    ...:      2079, 2154, 2155, 2156, 2157, 2158, 2159, 2163, 2165,
    ...:      2166, 2167, 2183, 2184, 2208, 2210, 2212, 2213, 2221,
    ...:      2222, 2223, 2225, 2226, 2227, 2281, 2282, 2338, 2401,
    ...:      2611, 2612, 2639, 2640, 2649, 2700, 2775, 2776, 2785,
    ...:      3030, 3171, 3191, 3406, 3427, 3527, 3984, 3996, 3997,
    ...:      4024, 4323, 4331, 4332])

In [36]: [within[within>x][0] if len(within[within>x])>0 else 0 for x in indices]
Out[36]: [883, 1004, 2014, 3171, 3406, 3984, 4323, 4323, 0]
```

This is the pythonic approach called [list comprehension](https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Comprehensions.html) it's a shortened version of a `foreach` loop.  So if I were to expand this out:

```
result = []
for x in indices:
    # This next line is a boolean index into the array, if returns all of the items in the array that have a value greater than x
    y = within[within>x]
    # At this point, y is an array of all the items which are larger than x.  Since you wanted the first of these items, we'll just take the first item off of this new array, but it is possible that y is None (there are no values that match the condition), so there is a check for that
    if len(y) > 0:
         z = y[0]
    else:
         z = 0 # or None or whatever you like
    # Now add this value to the array that we are building
    result.append(z)
# Now result has the array
```

I wrote it this way, because it uses the vector operations (i.e. the boolean mask) and also leverages list comprehension, which is a much cleaner simpler way to write a foreach which returns an array.

Comment: This is one of the most confusing one liners. Can you please explain?